# How can I prevent markdown styling of R output in a quarto HTML document

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am printing a table that contains _ characters with kable() in a quarto file using an HTML output and it is italicizing and/or bolding the output rather than printing the _ characters. How can I print the output as is rather than converting it into italicized and/or bolded text?

I messed around with

```
#| output: asis
```

and it just further messed up the formatting.

You can see the problem if you render this:

````
```{r}
blah <- data.frame(word = c("abcde", "a_c_e", "_b___", "__c__"))

blah |> 
  knitr::kable()
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following trick: add the [parse-latex](https://github.com/tarleb/parse-latex) filter and render the kable to LaTeX, i.e.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
filters: [parse-latex.lua]
---

```{r}
blah <- data.frame(word = c("abcde", "a_c_e", "_b___", "__c__"))
```

```{r}
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| tbl-subcap: ["HTML table", "LaTeX table"]

blah |> 
  knitr::kable()

blah |> 
  knitr::kable(format = "latex")
```
````

**Result**:

[image]

Comment: That is high quality magic.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Kable generates raw HTML, which is then spliced back into the Markdown document. We can control at read time whether the contents of HTML elements should be parsed as Markdown or handled verbatim. For that, we'll have to disable the `markdown_in_html_blocks` Markdown extension:

```yaml
---
from: 'markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks'
---
```

The cells should now be passed through without being interpreted as Markdown.